# What does the error 'Enter a list of values.' mean? (Using jQuery datetimepicker in django admin form)

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, django-widget

**Edit**: it seems that when we use a `DateTimeField` in django, it expects two inputs, one with the date, and one with the time like this:

[image]

So I'll just create two fields, one for the time and one for the date, will post an answer if it works as expected.

---

I created a custom widget in order to replace the default django's datetime picker in my administration site.

To do so I followed these [instructions](https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2019/01/03/how-to-use-date-picker-with-django.html#xdsoft-datetimepicker)
but it ends up like this when I click save button:

[image]

I have no other specific errors in the logs.

For more details, here is the code:

settings.py:

```
DATE_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M']
```

app/templates/widgets/xdsoft_datetimepicker.html

```
{% include "django/forms/widgets/input.html" %}
<!-- jQuery -->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- XDSoft DateTimePicker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-DOS9W6NR+NFe1fUhEE0PGKY/fubbUCnOfTje2JMDw3Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha256-FEqEelWI3WouFOo2VWP/uJfs1y8KJ++FLh2Lbqc8SJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
  $(function () {
    $("input[name='{{ widget.name }}']").datetimepicker({
      format: 'd/m/Y H:i',
    });
  });
</script>
```

app/models.py:

```
class DatesAndDates(models.Model):
    date_time_1 = models.DateTimeField()
```

app/forms.py:

```
class DateForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = DatesAndDates
        widgets = {
            "date_time_1": XDSoftDateTimePickerInput(
            )
        }
        fields=["date_time_1"]
```

And Finally app/admin.py:

```
@admin.register(DatesAndDates)
class DatesAndDatesAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = DateForm
    list_display = ["date_time_1"]
```

Before trying this I just used a Charfield for the date and time and added the jQuery script by overriding the change_form.html template but i failed at converting the datetime string to a valid datetime type.

Thanks for reading and for the help.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

As i said in the edit:
When we use a `models.DateTimeField` Dango expects datas from two formfields, one for the date and one for the time. So as i said i created two fields in my model, one `models.DateField`and one `models.TimeField`. And here is the method i used to create my own Widget in my app:

app/widget.py:

```
from django.forms import DateInput, TimeInput

# Overriding DateInput and TimeInput's template with my own one
class XDSoftDatePickerInput(DateInput):
    template_name = 'widgets/xdsoft_datetimepicker.html'

class XDSoftTimePickerInput(TimeInput):
    template_name = 'widgets/xdsoft_datetimepicker.html'
```

app/templates/widgets/xdsoft_datetimepicker.html

```
{% include "django/forms/widgets/input.html" %}
<!-- jQuery -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <!-- XDSoft DateTimePicker -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-DOS9W6NR+NFe1fUhEE0PGKY/fubbUCnOfTje2JMDw3Y=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js" integrity="sha256-FEqEelWI3WouFOo2VWP/uJfs1y8KJ++FLh2Lbqc8SJk=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<script>
  $.datetimepicker.setLocale('fr');

  widget_name = '{{ widget.name }}'
  if (~widget_name.indexOf("date")){
    $(function () {
      $("input[name='{{ widget.name }}']").datetimepicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y',
          timepicker:false,
      });
    });
  }
  else{
    $(function () {
      $("input[name='{{ widget.name }}']").datetimepicker({
        format: 'H:i',
        datepicker:false,
      });
    });
  }
</script>
```

app/models.py:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    date_begin = models.DateField(verbose_name="Date début de l'évènement")
    hour_begin = models.TimeField(verbose_name="Heure début de l'évènement")
    date_end = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Date de fin de l'évènement")
    hour_end = models.TimeField(blank=True, null=True, verbose_name="Heure de Fin de l'évènement")
```

app/forms.py:

```
class EventForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Event
        widgets = {
            "date_begin": XDSoftDatePickerInput(
            ),
            "date_end": XDSoftDatePickerInput(
            ),
            "hour_begin": XDSoftTimePickerInput(
            ),
            "hour_end": XDSoftTimePickerInput(
            )
        }
        fields='__all__'
```

And voilà:

[image]

But there is a problem here:
Every time you'll use the widget, the all jquery script will be included in your page...

Answer (score 0):

To avoid multiple css/js loads, you can pass your media in your widget class like this:

```
class XDSoftDatePickerInput(DateInput):
    ...

    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": (
                'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.min.css',
            )
        }
        js = (
            "https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
            'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-datetimepicker/2.5.20/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js',
        )
```

Comment: Please explain what your code does and how it does it.

Comment: @M-Chen-3 https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/media/#assets-as-a-static-definition

Comment: Links do not help; you need to explain your answer more clearly.

Comment: I never said I couldn't read them. I'm simply pointing out that a good answer would be explained more clearly, and wouldn't rely on simply a link the documentation.